# How do I place a react link on tds of a table?

Tags: reactjs, html-table

I want to have all the td's from firstName to email be clickable to link to that specific contact. Do I have to put a Link wrapper on each div? Even if I do, I want the Link to wrap around the entire td, not just the text within it so that the user can click on any part of the td rather than the text itself.

```
<tr key={index}>
  <td><Link to={`/${contact.id}`}><div>{contact.firstName}</div></Link></td>
  <td>{contact.lastName}</td>
  <td>{contact.city}</td>
  <td>{contact.phone}</td>
  <td>{contact.email}</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" value="readOnly" checked={that.state.deleteList.includes(contact.id)} onClick={that.addToDeleteList.bind(that, contact.id)}/></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You can do that by assign css properties so the `Link` will fill the `td`

Answer (score 2):

For link part you are doing it correctly. Just remove `<div>` from Link tag.

To make whole table cell clickable irrespective of content within it set display of Link to block via css or inlinke css.
e.g.

```
display: block
```

Here is CSS for the same.

```
td a {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: I did what you put but I can't seem to get rid of the padding on td even though I set it to 0 in CSS. Also, how do I make the td be clickable even when there is no content inside?

Comment: Attach `onClick` event handler on td if it is not having any content.